# GL_2 representation in GL_3 has wrong matrix

Tags: combinatorics, representation-theory

In Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics Vol. 2 he asks us to consider $\varphi:\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow \mathrm{GL}_3(\mathbb{C})$ given by $$ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c& d \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} a^2 & 2ab & b^2 \\ ac & ad + bc & bd \\ c^2 & 2cd & d^2 \end{pmatrix}$$ I don't know where I surmised this because I don't think it's in Stanley, but this is supposed to come from the induced action of $\mathrm{GL}_2$ on $\mathrm{Sym}^2(\mathbb{C}^2)$ given by $A(v \otimes w) = Av \otimes Aw$. However, taking $e_1,e_2$ to be the standard basis for $\mathbb{C}^2$, we should have $$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}(e_1 \otimes e_1) = (ae_1 + ce_2) \otimes (ae_1 + ce_2) = a^2 e_1^2 + 2ac \, e_1e_2 + c^2 e_2^2$$ $$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}(e_1 \otimes e_2) = (ae_1 + ce_2) \otimes (b e_1 + de_2) = abe_1^2 + (ad + bc)e_1e_2 + cde_2^2$$ and similarly for $e_2 \otimes e_2$ so the matrix should be $$\begin{pmatrix} a^2 & ab & b^2 \\ 2ac & ad +bc & 2bd \\ c^2 & cd & d^2 \end{pmatrix}$$ which is about a transpose and a coordinate change away from the given representation. I suspect I am making some trivial mistake in my definitions but don't know what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the representation would look like if you used the basis $\{e_1\otimes e_1, 2(e_1\otimes e_2), e_2\otimes e_2\}$ for $Sym^2(\mathbb{C}^2)$.

This would absorb the 2's you are seeing in your second row and add 2's in rows one and three.

Comment: is that a standard basis for the symmetric powers? thanks!

Comment: It is pretty standard. It comes from the so called Veronese embedding of homogenous degree 1 polynomials into homogenous degree 2 polynomials in 2 variables. For example the embeding  takes $(x+y)$ to $(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2$, which is why the 2 shows up in the cross term.